# PHP - failed to open stream: No such file or directory but file exists

Tags: php, include, require

This is the error I'm getting when I try to require a PHP function file on my main page:

`require("./funkcije/vratiZadatke.php");`

I think this line itself works because I don't get an error there, but the file that file requires seem to not exist even though it does because I get this error:

```
Warning: require(../konekcija/konekcija.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taskmanager/funkcije/vratiZadatke.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../konekcija/konekcija.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taskmanager/funkcije/vratiZadatke.php on line 2
```

This is how the file is included:

```
require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
```

This is the structure of the entire project:
[image]

Comment: Use absolute paths, or a path relative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `__DIR__`. Relative paths can get tricky when dealing with directories and subdirectories.

Comment: Can you tell me which lines of code to change exactly? Just so I could follow an example. I've tried looking other answers up but I get confused where to include it.

Comment: You would change `require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";`